# invalid ELF header when trying to use QtWebEngine QML plugin on ARM

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi2, yocto, qt5.4, qtwebengine

## My Setup

On Debian 7.8, I built my own Linux + Qt 5.4 + QtWebEngine + QML plugins distribution for **Raspberry Pi 2** using **Yocto Poky**.

See excellent[Embarcados tutorial HERE](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-qt5-yocto-parte-1/#comment-2070870985)

```
mkdir -p ~/yocto/dl
cd ~/yocto
git clone -b fido git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky poky
cd poky
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi 
git clone -b fido https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5.git
git clone -b fido git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
git clone -b fido https://bitbucket.org/embarcados/meta-embarcados.git
```

## Config

```
otto@marvin:~/yocto/build$ vi ~/yocto/build/conf/bblayers.conf 

# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-embarcados \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-embarcados/meta-rpi \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-qt5 \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-openembedded/meta-ruby \
  /home/otto/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/otto/yocto/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/otto/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  /home/otto/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/otto/yocto/poky/meta-yocto \
  "
```

In the `/home/otto/yocto/build/conf/local.conf` add `MACHINE = "raspberrypi2"`

### Added QtWebEngine + QML plugins to image

```
vi ../poky/meta-embarcados/meta-rpi/recipes-core/images/qt5-image-demo.bbappend

IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
           packagegroup-qt5-machine-related \
           qtwebengine \                   => /usr/lib/qt5/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess
           qtwebengine-qmlplugins \        => /usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtWebEngine
                        "
```

## Built the image

```
cd ~/yocto
. poky/oe-init-build-env build
bitbake qt5-image-demo
```

## Running my simple QML

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# more chromium.qml 
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebEngine 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        url: "file:///home/root/hello.html"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

## The Error

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmlscene chromium.qml --platform eglfs
file:///home/root/chromium.qml:3 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtWebEngine": Cannot load library /usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin.so: (/usr/lib/libexpat.so.1: invalid ELF header)
```

Any pointers?
What is the `invalid ELF header` telling?